# linking librarys as a part of flags in toolchain file in cmake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, cmake-format

i've tried to add `PROFILE` to the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPES`. For this I need to add `-finstrument-functions`to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` in the toolchain file and link the belonging library with the absolut path in the CMakeLists.txt via `target_link_libraries`. So far so good and unproblematic.

But when refreshing the buildinformations cmake checks if the compiler stil does it's job. And now "is not able to compile a simple test program", due to the lack of the needed library, which is linked later in the CMakeLists.

So I commented the `-finstrument-functions` flag and the testprogramm could be compiled.

I've tried to:
- Set librarie and path as a part of the CXX flags with -L  -l:

- Use the `link_directories(<dir>)` command as well as `SET(CMAKE_LINK_DIRECTORIES_BEFORE <Path> )` and `SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH  <Path>)`
- Set variables in the toolchainfile and call them later in the cmakelists:

```
SET(ADDITIONAL_PROFILE_LIBRARY  "$ENV{QNX_BASE}/target/qnx7/armle-v7/usr/liblibprofilingS.a")
SET(ADDITIONAL_PROFILE_FLAGS "-finstrument-functions")
```

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" "${ADDITIONAL_PROFILE_FLAGS}")
add_executable(toolchainTester main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(toolchainTester ${ADDITIONAL_PROFILE_LIBRARY})
```

But then getting the error: `mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** No rule to make target 'C:/qnx700/target/qnx7/armle-v7/usr/liblibprofilingS.a', needed by '../out/profileout'.  Stop.`

Got anyone any more ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `C:/qnx700/target/qnx7/armle-v7/usr/liblibprofilingS.a` and where does it come from? Does the file exists? Are you sure there are two `liblib` in the filename?

Comment: Great. Thanks. There was a missing '/' between the liblib that I didn't see.

Answer (score 0):

If there anyone out there, looking for the same workaround how to manage different flags and libraries for different profiles, this is one working way:

**First set variables in the toolchainfile**

```
SET(ADDITIONAL_PROFILE_LIBRARY  "$ENV{QNX_BASE}/target/qnx7/armle-v7/usr/lib/libprofilingS.a")
SET(ADDITIONAL_CXX_FLAGS "-finstrument-functions")
```

**The call/overright them in the CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" "${ADDITIONAL_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(toolchainTester main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(toolchainTester ${ADDITIONAL_PROFILE_LIBRARY})
```